# Why font is reseting after swtiching to Arabic? (textbox)

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a notepad program, the font system is fully working but after swtiching my language to arabic, font will be changed to visual studio's default font. there is absolutely no way to revert the font (even deleting the arabic part) except changing font in font tab again.

i've tried reseting the font on each letter (probably not a good way and im aware from that), also tried to change richtextbox's settings but still didnt work. i'd be greatful if you could tell me what's the solution? By the way, here is how i change the font:

```vb
        If FontDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            RichTextBox1.Font = FontDialog1.Font
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\font.txt", FontDialog1.Font.FontFamily.Name, False)
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\fontsi.txt", FontDialog1.Font.Size, False)
        End If
```

(and im partly sure that this isnt my code's fault, the code is just writing/reading/setting font)

Comment: At what point is the "font changed to visual studio's default font"? Is it when the program you made is restarted?

Comment: no, it immediately affects the text (letters after swtiching language will be changed to ms default's font)

Comment: How do you change the application's current language? What font are you using, originally, and which one is set when you change the language (is it the same font)?

Comment: its the same for any font and i it happens when i change the system's language (alt+shift). i believe that it'll swtich to microsoft sans serif

Comment: The System shortcut changes the Keyboard layout, not the language. This doesn't change the Font (unless you're referring to something else). If you actually change the language and the current Font doesn't support the language charset, if will fallback to a Font surrogate that, possibly, supports it. Microsoft Sans Serif doesn't support much. If you change the language (the language, not the Keyboard layout) it will fallback to a system-defined surrogate. The surrogate depends on the original system installation (it's a system setting, you can find it in the registry).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you post this: `My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(...)`? Is it related to the question or it just happened to be there?

Comment: @Jimi thanks for your explanation, i think its unfixable because it only happens to my own program, it works fine on other programs (e.g notepad), and that line is meant to show that i save and open the font aswell (since _maybe_ its related to that)

Comment: Try to set the Font (in the Designer) to Segoe UI. It supports Arabic and it's usually mapped correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments but I found out a good way to fix this problem (if you're creating a english-arabic notepad and you're facing the same problem, here is the solution) :
Basically I changed `RichTextBox1.Font =` to `RichTextBox1.SelectionFont= New Font(` and it seems to be working, it wasn't because richtextbox itself, just a little problem with my code